# restore the 0-1 matrix based on the row sums and column sums

Tags: java, algorithm

**PLEASE NOTE:**
**This question is quite long and may cost some time to read:**

I had this problem in a coding test:

> Say we have a 0-1 matrix with 2 rows and N columns, given the U=the
>   sum of upper row, and the L=the sum of low row, and int[] C= the array
>   containing the sum of each column, return the String representation of
>   the matrix. If there are more than one, return any of them. If no
>   matrix satisfies, return "IMPOSSIBLE".

example1:

> U=3,L=2,C=[2,1,1,0,1] return String="11100,10001"(two rows are
>   seperated by ",")

I got the correctness rete of 50% and speed rate of 14% with below methods:

my thought:

> 1. if U+L != the sum of elements in C, return "IMPOSSIBLE";
> 2. otherwise, initilize the matrix with 0, and use a for loop to visit each element in C:
>      if C[i]==2, set elements in each row with 1;
>      if C[i]==0 set elements in each row with 0;
>      if C[i]==1 && 0<U, set element in upper row with 1 and element in low row with 0, and U--,
>      otherwise, set element in upper row with 0 and element in low row with 1;
> 3. finally we visit each elemenet in the matrix to get the result String(with StringBuilder.append()).

Can anybody help me to improve it? 
I cann't figure out a better solution after a long time thinking. 
This solution should be 100% correct I think, and `O(N)` should be the minum time complexity in which `N` is the total number of matrix elements.

---

----Update:

```
class Solution {
public String solution(int U, int L, int[] C) {
    // write your code in Java SE 8
    int N=C.length;

    int colSum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        colSum+=C[i];
    }
    if(colSum!=U+L){
        return "IMPOSSIBLE";
    }


    String[] upRow=new String[N];
    String[] lowRow=new String[N];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        if(C[i]==2){
            upRow[i]="1";
            lowRow[i]="1";
            U--;
            L--;
        }else if(C[i]==0){
            upRow[i]="0";
            lowRow[i]="0";
        }else{
            if(0<U){
                upRow[i]="1";
                lowRow[i]="0";
                U--;
            }else{
                upRow[i]="0";
                lowRow[i]="1";       
            }           
        }
    }

    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        sb.append(upRow[i]);
    }
    sb.append(",");
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        sb.append(lowRow[i]);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: If you have U=2 L=0 C=[2] your algorithm will return 1,1 instead of recognizing that it's not possible and this is just one example. As to the speed 14% I don't know what it means, how is it calculated? Post your code.

Comment: @Oleg this can probably be mitigated by checking after string construction whether the matrix fulfills the criteria. (probably should represent as an array for easier summing)

Comment: @Oleg You are right. If U or L is larger than the non-zero elements count in C, it is IMPOSSIBLE.

Comment: @Oleg I don't know the 14%, either. I guess it means only 14% test cases can produce results under the time limit.

Comment: The test platform prohibit me review my codes, so I can't post it here. I can only recall my ideas.@Oleg

Comment: @Arch2K Yes but this is not enough, you also need to check that there are no other solutions. For example U=2 L=2 C[1,1,2] OP's algorithm will return 111,001 which is wrong and yet 101,011 solves it.

Comment: "If U or L is larger than the non-zero elements count in C, it is IMPOSSIBLE." I'm not sure that this check is enough to find all the impossible inputs, maybe. See my previous comment for another problem with your solution.

Comment: @Oleg It seems that a greedy method is wrong. Maybe a DP solution is needed. PS, I really should use enough test cases to verify the correctness of my idea, before coding.

Comment: @Oleg we should firstly find all "2" in the C array, fullfill "1" in the upper& bottom row seperately, meanwhile do U--&L--. If U<0 or L<0. return "IMPOSSIBLE".

Comment: This might be correct, I don't see a problem with it just thinking about it. Can't help you further without code.

Comment: I can't find the Java code.

Comment: @Oleg Ah, I was mistaken by the original post. I thought that C would be iterated once first. What should work is to iterate C once, and decrement the variable U by every instance in which C is (1,1). Then, the greedy method would generate a solution. This would have a time complexity of O(2n) = O(n)

Comment: @Arch2K I posted a solution based on the comments, tested with different inputs, seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

The solution based on the comments:

```
public static String check(int[] c, int u, int l) {
    // decrease the sum of upper and lower rows by the number of sum 2 columns
    int twos = (int) Arrays.stream(c).filter(a -> a == 2).count();
    u -= twos;
    l -= twos;

    StringBuilder upper = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder lower = new StringBuilder();

    for (int a : c) {
        switch (a) {
        // sum was already decreased, just add 1 to each row
        case 2: 
            upper.append('1');
            lower.append('1');
            break;
        // first put 1 in the upper row and decrease it's sum until it reaches 0 then switch to lower row
        case 1: 
            if (u > 0) {
                upper.append('1');
                lower.append('0');
                u--;
            } else {
                upper.append('0');
                lower.append('1');
                l--;
            }
            break;
        case 0:
            upper.append('0');
            lower.append('0');
        }
    }

    // if and only if the sum of both rows is now 0 a solution was found otherwise return "IMPOSSIBLE"
    return u == 0 && l == 0 ? upper.toString() + "," + lower.toString() : "IMPOSSIBLE";
}
```

It possible to know before reaching the end that there is no solution if `u` or `l` are less than `0` and checks can be added in the code for example:

```
if (u < 0 || l < 0)
    return "IMPOSSIBLE";
```

Can be added before the `for` loop. And more checks can be added in the loop. In the real world it might make the code slower or faster, depending on many factors(branch prediction, more possible or impossible...). It won't change the complexity.

Comment: Awesome. Also in your code there is only one for loop, which is faster than my original solution.

Comment: @ZhaoGang `stream` also iterates over all the elements so it's the same as another for loop. I wonder what would be the speed rate score.

Comment: Indeed. Usually (at least in Leetcode), O(2n) and O(n) solutions should both pass all test cases. A time limit exception only occurs on time complexity larger than O(n), for example, O(nlng), or O(n^2) @Oleg